# CordaApp with Spring Boot Api different response

Tags: corda

I have integrated the cordapp with spring boot .One strange observation we found that the response differs coming from  the cordawebserver  and spring boot server for example

> Blockquote

API :GET:   market/me
gives

```
{
 “me”: {
   “commonName”: null,
   “organisationUnit”: null,
   “organisation”: “PartyG-CT”,
   “locality”: “Tokyo”,
   “state”: null,
   “country”: “JP”,
   “x500Principal”: {
     “name”: “O=PartyG-CT,L=Tokyo,C=JP”,
     “encoded”: “MDExCzAJBgNVBAYTAkpQMQ4wDAYDVQQHDAVUb2t5bzESMBAGA1UECgwJUGFydHlHLUNU”
   }
 }
}
```

with Spring boot
while with cordawebserver we are getting :

```
   {
 “me”: “C=JP,L=Tokyo,O=PartyG-CT”
}
```

Same behaviour we are finding the same for different APIs Any help will be appreciated

```
@GET
        @Path("peers")
        @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   // CordaX500Name
        public Map<String, List<CordaX500Name>> getPeers() {
            List<NodeInfo> nodeInfoSnapshot = proxy.networkMapSnapshot();
            return ImmutableMap.of(
                    "peers",
                    nodeInfoSnapshot
                            .stream()
                            .map(node -> node.getLegalIdentities().get(0).getName())
                            .filter(name -> !name.equals(myLegalName) && !name.getOrganisation().equals(controllerName)
                                    && !name.getOrganisation().equals(NETWORK_MAP_NAME))
                            .collect(toList()));
        }


//boot entry point
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class FacilityServer  {


        @Autowired
        public  static NodeRPCConnection nodeRPCConnection;
        /**
         * Starts our Spring Boot application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
            springApplication.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
            springApplication.run(FacilityServer.class, args);
        }

        @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void initiateFacilityObserverPostStartup() throws Exception{

            FacilityObserver.startFacilityWatch();

        }



// this class for using the jersey instead of spring rest impltn
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {



    public JerseyConfig() {



    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        register(MarketApi.class);
        //register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the API endpoint you've written for :GET: market/me in the Spring Boot server?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/market/me .      please note I am not using the Corda webserver ,I am using spring boot .

Comment: That's the URL. There will be an underlying handler that is being called. It sounds like the handler code in the Spring Boot webserver differs from the handler code in the built-in webserver.

Comment: i have edited the post for the handler please have a look

Comment: Where is the Spring Boot handler? That handler will only be used by the built-in webserver. You must be defining another handler in the Spring Boot webserver.

Comment: My concern is why the response is different for the same end point with different webservers as shown above .There is no change in the code for both the implementation.

Comment: @joel i have updated the Question for the boot handler

Comment: That's not the Spring Boot handler. It would be something like https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver/blob/release-V3/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/controllers/StandardController.kt#L30.

Comment: If you see that in question lines starting with @GET
        Path("peers")
        Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) is the spring controller .Again ,I am using spring boot with jersey that y path annotation  has come instead getMapping

Comment: Haha, I'm so confused :) Are you able to upload the CorDapp somewhere for me to take a look?

Comment: No problem. I believe that when you run your nodes, you are somehow including another API. The response you get when getting `/me` corresponds exactly to what you'd get with this API: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/api/ExampleApi.kt.

Comment: yes that will be because i used .toString().If you see /peers it is giving the different response.I am assuming that we need to override the .tostring() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ;According to the corda documentation we need to register cordajackson mapper .Then, we will be able to get the same response as in corda webserer.
for example:

```
List<StateAndRef<YourState>> vaultStatesList =  vaultStates.getStates();  

ObjectMapper mapper = JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(vaultStatesList);
```